# MySQL Query Not Inserting All Records (using PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a fairly large amount of data that I'm trying to insert into MySQL.  It's a data dump from a provider that is about 47,500 records.  Right now I'm simply testing the insert method through a PHP script just to get things dialed in.

What I'm seeing is that, first, the inserts will continue to happen long after the PHP script "finishes".  So by the time I can see the browser no longer has an "X" to cancel the request and now has a "reload" (indicating the script is done from the browser perspective) I can see for a good 10+ minutes that inserts are still occurring.  I assume this is MySQL caching the queries.  Is there any way to keep the script "alive" until all queries have completed?  I put a 15 minute timeout on my script.

Second, and more disturbing, is that I won't get every insert.  Of the 47,500 records I'll get anywhere between 28,000 and 38,000 records but never more - and that number is random each time I run the script.  Anything I can do about that?

Lastly, I have a couple simple echo statements at the end of my script for debugging, these never fire - leading me to believe that a time out might be happening (although I don't get any errors about time-outs or memory outages). I'm thinking this has something to do with the problem but am not sure.

I tried changing my table to an archive table but not only didn't that help but it also means I lose the ability to update the records in the table when I want to, I did it only as a test.

Right now the insert is in a simple loop, it loops each record in the JSON data that I get from the source and runs an insert statement, then on to the next iteration.  Should I be trying to instead using the loop to build a massive insert and run a single insert statement at the end?  My concern with this is that I fear I would go beyond my max_allowed_packet configuration that is hard coded by my hosting provider.

So I guess the real question is what is the best method to insert nearly 50,000 records into MySQL using PHP based on what I've explained here.

Comment: Please post your code and table structures as well. I can easily insert 100.000+ records within 1-2 secs with PHP, but until I don't see your code, I can't really help.

Comment: Check your timeout and memory limit settings.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by doing a batch insert.  I did some calculations and found that even inserting just 10,000 records in a single insert statement was taking far less time and was less than 1MB of data, that seems to be the trick.  Thank you for taking the time to answer!!!